# Making A New Paramatirized Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, animation, parameters

I want to run my function in a different thread but the problem is that the function needs a paramater.

If I try it with a function that doesn't need paramters(CPUPlay()) its ok:

```
private void OpenNewThread(bool open)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CPUPlay));
    }
```

But if I try it with a function that needs parameters, it doesn't work:

```
private void OpenNewThread(bool open)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CloseOpenAnimation));
    thread.Start(open);
}
```

So how can I run a function with parameters in a different thread?

Comment: Really, when do you people learn that "doesn't work" is **no** error description?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheat and use delegates

```
private void OpenNewThread(bool open)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
        () => CloseOpenAnimation(open)));
    thread.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does your function match this signature?

```
public void CloseOpenAnimation(object argument)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try BackgroundWorker object. There is an object parameter Argument you can use.

```
BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
bg.DoWork+=new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
bg.RunWorkerAsync(5);

static void  bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
            int j = (int)e.Argument;
}
```

where e.Argument is of type object.